# How to add two url argument to Django template url tag?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-urls

- my django version is 2.0.5
- my os version is ubuntu 20.04
- I want to pass two url argument in  Django template url tag,my url code is blow

```py
path('download/<str:bucket>/<str:object>/',views.Download.as_view(), name='download'),# appname= storage
```

- the code below can work

```html
<a href="{% url 'storage:download'  bucket=bucket  object='object.Key'    %}">{{ object.Key }}</a>
```

but the the code below doesn't work

```html
 <a href="{% url 'storage:download'  bucket=bucket object= object.Key %}">{{ object.Key }}</a>
```

```html
 <a href="{% url 'storage:download' bucket object.Key %}">{{ object.Key }}</a>
```

when django rendering this page ,it raise an `NoReverseMatch at /storage/file/MonitorNodes/`error

```
NoReverseMatch at /storage/file/MonitorNodes/
Reverse for 'download' with keyword arguments '{'bucket': 'MonitorNodes', 'object': 'directory/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['storage/download/(?P<bucket>[^/]+)/(?P<object>[^/]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/file/MonitorNodes/
Django Version: 2.0.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'download' with keyword arguments '{'bucket': 'MonitorNodes', 'object': 'directory/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['storage/download/(?P<bucket>[^/]+)/(?P<object>[^/]+)/$']
Exception Location: /home/cedar/dashboard/.dashboard-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 632
Python Executable:  /home/cedar/dashboard/.dashboard-env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/cedar/dashboard',
 '/home/cedar/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.5.842923320/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/cedar/dashboard/.dashboard-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 21 May 2021 11:27:39 +0800
```

#### is there any way to make my code work?

Comment: “object.Key” has a forward slash as the last character, this is not valid as a “str” path parameter cannot contain a forward slash

Comment: Try `<path:object>` instead of `<str:object>` if the argument is meant to have slashes.

Comment: thank you,the code work aftef replace `str` to `path`